# any good articles that eplain diff. DB's side-by-side?

Tags: database

We are in the process of a database redesign & have heard stuff about all the different options: hadoop, cassandra, oracle, etc. Is there a good article that compares each of the major DB's side-by-side on performance & features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Comparison of relational database management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_relational_database_management_systems)

[NoSQL](http://nosql-database.org/links.html)